# CoffeeScript - class extend from a subparent

Tags: class, coffeescript, three.js

is there a particular method for create a class derivate from a child of a native class ?
Here is my query :

```
class One
    constructor : () ->

class Two extends One
    constructor : () ->
        super()

class Three extends Two
    constructor : () ->
        super()
```

In result, the Three parent class is the One. How can i just pick the second ?
The process look maybe illogical but i work with **Threejs** and when i want extend the Mesh Class, it return the Object3D class...
Thanks !

Comment: The code seems to work as expected. See [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20One%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%0Aclass%20Two%20extends%20One%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert('I%20am%20in%20two')%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0A%0Aclass%20Three%20extends%20Two%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0A%0Ax%20%3D%20new%20Three)

Comment: The Mesh and Object3D classes in Threejs were written by you in CoffeeScript? Or do they come from the library itself? Please keep in mind that there's no "class" concept in JavaScript and some libraries "emulate" them differently.

Comment: depending on object structure, mixins, maybe? http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/classes_and_objects/mixins

Comment: i found a solution :
Instead of use the super method, i call like this :
    Two.call(this, parameters)